# Storm Word Count Topology - Concept issue with number of executions

Tags: java, apache-storm, word-count

Good afternoon, I am following the Storm-starter WordCountTopology [here](https://github.com/nathanmarz/storm-starter). For reference, here are the Java files.

This is the main file:

```
public class WordCountTopology {
public static class SplitSentence extends ShellBolt implements IRichBolt {

public SplitSentence() {
  super("python", "splitsentence.py");
}

@Override
public void declareOutputFields(OutputFieldsDeclarer declarer) {
  declarer.declare(new Fields("word"));
}

@Override
public Map<String, Object> getComponentConfiguration() {
  return null;
}
}

public static class WordCount extends BaseBasicBolt {
Map<String, Integer> counts = new HashMap<String, Integer>();

@Override
public void execute(Tuple tuple, BasicOutputCollector collector) {
  String word = tuple.getString(0);
  Integer count = counts.get(word);
  if (count == null)
    count = 0;
  count++;
  counts.put(word, count);
  collector.emit(new Values(word, count));
}

@Override
public void declareOutputFields(OutputFieldsDeclarer declarer) {
  declarer.declare(new Fields("word", "count"));
}
}

public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

TopologyBuilder builder = new TopologyBuilder();

builder.setSpout("spout", new TextFileSpout(), 5);

builder.setBolt("split", new SplitSentence(), 8).shuffleGrouping("spout");
builder.setBolt("count", new WordCount(), 12).fieldsGrouping("split", new Fields("word"));

Config conf = new Config();
conf.setDebug(true);

if (args != null && args.length > 0) {
  conf.setNumWorkers(3);

  StormSubmitter.submitTopology(args[0], conf, builder.createTopology());
}
else {
  conf.setMaxTaskParallelism(3);
  LocalCluster cluster = new LocalCluster();
  cluster.submitTopology("word-count", conf, builder.createTopology());
  Thread.sleep(10000);
  cluster.shutdown();
}
}
}
```

Instead of reading from a random String[], I would like just one read from one sentence:

```
public class TextFileSpout extends BaseRichSpout {
    SpoutOutputCollector _collector;
    String sentence = "";
    String line = "";
    String splitBy = ",";
    BufferedReader br = null;

    @Override
    public void open(Map conf, TopologyContext context,
            SpoutOutputCollector collector) {
        _collector = collector;

    }

    @Override
    public void nextTuple() {
        Utils.sleep(100);
        sentence = "wordOne wordTwo";
        _collector.emit(new Values(sentence));
        System.out.println(sentence);
    }

    @Override
    public void ack(Object id) {
    }

    @Override
    public void fail(Object id) {
    }

    @Override
    public void declareOutputFields(OutputFieldsDeclarer declarer) {
        declarer.declare(new Fields("word"));
    }

}
```

This code runs and the output is a lot of threads/emits. The problem is that the program executes repeatedly reads that one sentence 85 times instead of just once. I'm guessing this is because the original code executes multiple times new random sentences.

What is causing NextTuple to be called so many times?

Comment: could you please share your spout code

Comment: @user2720864 Shared spout code. Sorry about that

Answer (score 0):

You should move the file initialize code with in open method , otherwise  every single time the nextTuple is called your file handler will be initialized.

EDIT:

inside open method , do something like

```
    br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(csvFileToRead));
```

and then the logic to read file should be inside the nextTuple method

```
     while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
         // your logic
     }
```

Comment: I have moved the file initialization into open. The sentence generated is corrected with all the words in the file seperated by a space. However, nextTuple is called 86 times so my counts are 86x times bigger than they should be. I guess this narrows my whole problem down to figuring out how to make nextTuple called only one time. Thank you very much for your time.

Comment: the reading logic should be inside nextTuple method, updated my answer

Comment: Thanks for your response. Even if I remove the whole filereading portion and just make sentence a single word, nextTuple is called repeatedly 85 times. Do you know, in this example, how Storm decides how many times to run nextTuple? Maybe I missed a configuration somewhere. Thank you.

Comment: I simplified the code to read just a single sentence. I looked through the code and can't figure out what calls NextTuple. I need need the spout to run once and return wordOne: 1 and wordTwo: 1 instead of 85 and 85. Thank you

Comment: Storm is designed for streaming sources that emit data as it becomes available.  nextTuple() is called in an infinite loop so for your case, it needs to keep track it's position in your data source.  It should also track ack() and fail() calls if you want at least once processing.